# Warning because of old migration - how should that be solved?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

If I run `python -Wall manage.py test` this warning (and similar) occurs:

```
/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1453:
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField SignUpUser.signup_time received a naive datetime (2018-03-17 21:27:22.620074) while time zone support is active.RuntimeWarning)
```

But there is no such field for the model `SignUpUser` anymore. It's called `signup_timestamp`. The same error occurs on other fields. To fix these I changed `datetime.now` to the  django built-in timezone considering `timezone.now`. But the error messages also doesn't disappear. I think this occurs because of an old migration.

The site is already in production, but only me is developing. How should I fix this? Resetting all migration files and redo the migration with --fake-initial?

Comment: Does your code contains something like this ? `date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem. I had defined the default value for a `DateTimeField` with `datetime.now` and switched to `timezone.now`.
I had created migrations after each model change (proably to test them). This lead to one migration defining the default value without the timezone (`field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 2, 22, 15, 4, 702061)),`) and the next migration would fix this issue and add the timezone (`field=models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 3, 19, 22, 32, 951341, tzinfo=utc)),`).

When running the tests for the model (`python manage.py test app_name`) then resulted in: `[...]/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1423: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Job.sub_date received a naive datetime (2018-08-02 22:15:04.702061) while time zone support is active.`

It seems like Django tries to apply the migrations to a database in which the timezone awareness is already defined. Not sure why it does that but that seems to be going on.

To prevent the warning occurring I had to squash the migrations up to the migration that changed the default value of the `DateTimeFiled` to be timezone aware. 
In my case this was migration `0007`, while `0006` added the default value without the timezone awareness. 
So the command to create the squash was:

```sh
$ python manage.py squashmigrations app_name 0007
```

This created a new migration file `0001_squashed_0007_auto_20180803_2122.py` which contains all the changes done by the migrations `0001` through `0007`. As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) says, this happens in an optimized manner so that only the final result of a series of migrations is build without the intermediate steps.

On new installs, instead of running the separate migrations `0001` through `0007` only the new squashed migration will be run.
You should keep the original migrations around for some time, to make sure the squashing did not introduce any issues:

> Once you’ve squashed your migration, you should then commit it alongside the migrations it replaces and distribute this change to all running instances of your application, making sure that they run migrate to store the change in their database.
>
> You must then transition the squashed migration to a normal migration by:
>
> - Deleting all the migration files it replaces.
> - Updating all migrations that depend on the deleted migrations to depend on the squashed migration instead.
> - Removing the replaces attribute in the Migration class of the squashed migration (this is how Django tells that it is a squashed migration).